# What is the best way to edit default article layout in communities?

Tags: community, knowledge

Does anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: what communities? lighnintg? is it for a specific template such as the napili? what would you like to change in the layout? please include more details =)

Comment: Yes it is for lightning/article/detail, I want to explore the possibilities on restructuring the HTML output. For example add extra classes. I have been looking around but I can't find any editable templates.

Comment: Btw I don't remember the name of the template but it is the first one Out Of The Box template.

Comment: ootb lightning components are not really editable, you will have to create your own component for this.

Comment: Thanks @glls, do you know where I can find the base component for "Article Content"?

Comment: unfortunately no, what is your use case exactly? would you like to change the layout of how articles are displayed after searching, OR when you select an article?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58792/discussion-between-glls-and-helmut-granda).